# Alternatives to java.util.regex

Tags: java, android

Are there any alternatives to **java.util.regex.Pattern** and **java.util.regex.Matcher** that can be used on android?

Comment: maybe you should be investigating the problem, rather than band-aiding it with another library.

Comment: What do you mean by "native crashes"? You are getting core dumps with `SIGSEGV`?

Comment: I guess the problem would require me downloading android source and debug the native libraries...seems much easier to look for an alternative.

Comment: @JonnyBoy: [`select` isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26). So before you go off looking for something else, make sure the problem really is where you think it is.

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, SIGSEGV.

Comment: any reason for the downvotes?  Seems like a simple question to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the retired Apache Jakarta RegEx library? http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp